# ASP.NET - Submitting a form does not pass data

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a class like so:

```
public class saveModel
    {
        public int ID{ get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Area")]
        public string Area { get; set; }
        public string AreaDescription { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Model")]
        public string Model { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Description")]

}
```

and in my controller I have this:

```
[Authorize]
        public ActionResult ModelEdit(int id)
        {

            saveModel model = webService.getModel(id);

            return View(model);
        }

        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ModelEdit(saveModel model)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

and in view I have this:

```
@model MyApp.Models.saveModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ModelID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ModelID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ModelID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Area, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Area, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Area, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AreaDescription, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AreaDescription, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AreaDescription, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Model, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Model, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Model, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
}
```

The problem I am having is when I press the save button, it goes to the correct method, but my saveModel is empty on submit...what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try including the from body attribute as below

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ModelEdit([FromBody]saveModel model)
{
    return View();
}
```

if it doesn't solve your problem, then an invalid or an empty value is being passed to your ID field. You can check the ModelState property, which will point to the right field.

Comment: That solution did not work, ill check the ModelState....how do I do that?

Comment: Figure it out how to check the ModelState...I got this error: Exception = {"The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'MyApp.Models.saveModel' failed because no type converter can convert between these types."}

Comment: Ahhhh the problem is with model.Model it doesn't like it.

Comment: Im going to change the name of it to Title